# What did Trump mean by "Nambia"?

Tags: donald-trump, healthcare, africa

The pronunciation suggests he meant either the Gambia, Namibia or Zambia. Which is most plausible, given his praising of the healthcare services in "Nambia"?

Comment: Could you clarify when he said "Nambia"? As is, this question won't make sense in a year.

Comment: If it'd help people hate the question less, I could reword it as "which of these three nations has the best healthcare system?"

Comment: This is clearly about political processes and policies. It flows from a policy speech of Donald Trump made at the UN and is an effort to discern the intended U.S. policy from the speech. Indeed the answer is really more truly political and appropriate for the forum that the gaffe itself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This isn't a definitive statement of what President Trump intended to say, or the original written content, but the White House transcript of the speech has apparently replaced ["Nambia" with "Namibia".](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2017/09/20/trumps-puzzling-speech-to-african-leaders-annotated/?utm_term=.e950967ba9dd#annotations:12725202)